# Why does AWS EMR require 2 different security groups for Master and Core/Task nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-security-group

I am setting up an EMR job and finding that I must specify Master and Core/Task specific security groups. What is the point of having 2? If I run in `client` mode - I will only utilize the Master security group anyways. And I believe if I run the EMR job on `cluster` mode it should only utilize the security group of core/task is this not correct?

That is at least my understanding since when I choose between `client` or `cluster` mode it tells me this:

> Run your driver on a slave node (cluster mode) or on the master node as an external client (client mode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Working With Amazon EMR-Managed Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html):

The Security Group on the **Master node** allows:

- Communication from Master nodes of other Amazon EMR clusters
- Communication from the Core and Task nodes
- Communication from the AWS cluster manager to control the cluster

The Security Group on the **Core/Task nodes** allows:

- Communication from other Core and Task nodes
- Communication from the Master node

Typically, the Security Group on the Master node is also opened so that you can directly connect with it (eg to run command-line Hive).

Access to the Core/Task nodes is exclusively done via the Master node. Any submitted jobs go to the Master node, then to the Core/Task nodes.

Comment: mm okay. So if outside connection attempting to get to Core/Task nodes has to first go through the Master node?

Comment: Correct. There should be no reason to directly connect to the Core/Task nodes.